# the transition for the div after hover is not working

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a product card with a transition on hover effect but the transition is not working at all.

```
    <div className="maincard container">
            
              <div className="bordercard card">
                <div className="imgdiv image">
                  <img src={shirt} className='productimg' alt='Img not available' />
                </div>
                <div className="subcard content">
                  <div className="titleText">{title}</div>
                  <div className="animatediv">
                    <div className="description">{description}</div>
                    <div className="size"></div>
                  </div>
                  <div className="price">{price}</div>
                  
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
```

the CSS is below

```
.maincard {
    width: 16%;
    height: 20%;
    /* border: 1px solid white; */
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    margin: 10px;
    /* margin-top: 60px; */
    position: relative;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    
}

.maincard .bordercard {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: all 1s ease-in;
}

.productPageDetails {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.subcard {
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
    /* border: 1px solid white; */
}



.productimg {
    position: relative;
    margin-top: -50px;
    margin: 0px auto;
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    object-fit: cover;
    /* margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto; */
    /* border: 1px solid white; */
    opacity: 1;
    z-index: 2;
}





.titleText {
    display: block;
    font-family: monospace;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    text-align: center;
}



.description {
    justify-content: space-between;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 2vb;
    padding: 10px;
    transition: 1s ease-in;
}

.animatediv{
    display: none;
    transition: all 1s ease-in;
    border: 1px solid white;
}
.maincard .bordercard:hover .animatediv{
    display: flex;
    transition: all 1s ease-in;
}

.price {
    text-align: right;
    margin: 10px 0px 0px 0px;
    font-size: 3vb;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

I know the CSS is chuncky and not refine but I am trying to learn pure CSS hence the code. the transition on "animatediv" is not working. i have tried giving every attribute the transition property but it did not work. is there something wrong with the overall code?

Comment: What are you trying to animate? If you want to animate something appearing you can't use the `display` property, see: [Transitions on the CSS display property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3331353/transitions-on-the-css-display-property)